# I need to get all the values from the html page (content=""), but I do not know which tag to search for (content="")

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is how the html code with the price looks like

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="121080">
```

I made this search code, but I don't know which tag to look for the price by

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://')

    let arr = await page.evaluate(() => {

        let text = document.getElementsByClassName('')
        return text
    })

    console.log(arr)

})()
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName isn’t useful if the element has no class attribute.  Consider [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `getElementsByClassName`  is useless unless the HTML element has a class.

You should look into [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://');

    let price = await page.evaluate(() => {
        // Find the <meta> tag with itemprop="price"
        let metaTag = document.querySelector('meta[itemprop="price"]');
        // Extract the content attribute value
        return metaTag ? metaTag.getAttribute('content') : null;
    });

    console.log('Price:', price);

    await browser.close();
})();
```